# How do I vertically center my content on my swiftui app?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm a beginner here, and just trying to put together a simple form and button (right now they don't do anything). For some reason I can't seem to move the form -- which is just going to be one text input by the way, so open to using a different method other than form -- to be centered vertically. Can anyone help me diagnose the problem? Here is my code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct CreateTopic: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Create Topic")
                .font(.largeTitle)
            Spacer() // <-- Add a Spacer view above the Form view
            Form {
                TextField("Name", text: $name)
                //                TextField("Email", text: $email)
                //                TextField("Phone", text: $phone)
            }
            .frame(height: 100)
            Spacer() // <-- Add a Spacer view below the Form view
            NavigationView {
                StandardButton(text: "Test", action: {})
            }
        }
        .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 0, maxHeight: .infinity)
    }

    @State private var name = ""
//    @State private var email = ""
//    @State private var phone = ""
}


struct CreateTopic_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        CreateTopic()
    }
}
```

I tried adding that Spacer() above the Form, which didn't really do anything. It did however move the button.

Should I not be using a Form if I am only looking to use one simple text input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple misunderstandings here. We can quickly solve them.

1. `Form` is a scrollable form. It is typically meant to encompass the entire screen. And if you use a form, you will not be able to center its content. Forms always lay out their subviews top-to-bottom. You *could* center a form within a larger view, but I wouldn't. I ran your code and you can scroll the form within the 100pt-tall rectangle. It's just weird.
2. `NavigationView` is meant to wrap the entire screen, not just a single button. It does things like add a navigation bar, display a title, and support buttons in the corners of the screen. It also supports the standard in-and-out screen transitions across all of iOS. Think of the Messages app and what happens when you tap into a conversation. `NavigationView` does that stuff.

With these two clarifications in mind, I would rewrite your view one of two ways.

**Option 1, using a Form**

```swift
struct CreateTopic: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Form {
                Section {
                    TextField("Name", text: $name)
                        .textContentType(.name)
                    
                    TextField("Email", text: $email)
                        .textContentType(.emailAddress)
                    
                    TextField("Phone", text: $phone)
                        .textContentType(.telephoneNumber)
                        .keyboardType(.phonePad)
                }
                
                Section {
                    Button("Create") {
                        // Create the topic
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("Create Topic")
        }
    }
    
    @State private var name = ""
    @State private var email = ""
    @State private var phone = ""
}
```

[image: Option 1]

**Option 2, without a Form, centering your text fields like you wanted**

```swift
struct CreateTopic: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                TextField("Name", text: $name)
                    .textContentType(.name)
                
                TextField("Email", text: $email)
                    .textContentType(.emailAddress)
                
                TextField("Phone", text: $phone)
                    .textContentType(.telephoneNumber)
                    .keyboardType(.phonePad)
                
                Button("Create") {
                    // Create the topic
                }
            }
            .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
            .padding()
            .frame(maxHeight: .infinity)
            .background(Color(.systemGroupedBackground))
            .navigationTitle("Create Topic")
        }
    }
    
    @State private var name = ""
    @State private var email = ""
    @State private var phone = ""
}
```

[image: Option 2]

`Form` fits the style of iOS more, but the second option looks fine and could be what you wanted.

Comment: this works for me, thank you!

question for you -- will a VStack inside of a NavigationView always center istelf? It seems like thats the key in your solution.

Comment: @dandaman11 In general, SwiftUI views are centered by default. The exception is List/Form/ScrollView. In those exceptions, it is difficult (but not impossible) to center. I only used a VStack because it seems like what you'd want for aligning your fields vertically. Oh, and .frame(maxHeight: .infinity) is what centers it I think. Try removing that and confirm.